# Problem with parentheses in Woocommerce cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with Woocommerce + "Yith deposits and down payments" plugin.
The page shows:

$26.997
(of
$93.980
)

And I need the site shows this:

$26.997
(of)
$93.980

This is the code from this part:

```
            if( $grand_total ) {
$total_html .= apply_filters( 'yith_wcdp_show_cart_total_html', sprintf( ' (%s <strong>%s</strong>)', __( 'of', 'yith-woocommerce-deposits-and-down-payments' ), wc_price( $grand_total ) ), WC()->cart );
            }
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update this part `sprintf( ' (%s) <strong>%s</strong>'`

Try this code

```
 if( $grand_total ) {
$total_html .= apply_filters( 'yith_wcdp_show_cart_total_html', sprintf( ' (%s) <strong>%s</strong>', __( 'of', 'yith-woocommerce-deposits-and-down-payments' ), wc_price( $grand_total ) ), WC()->cart );
            }
```

Comment: Please, Accept answer if your problem fixed.

Comment: Lovely! Thank you so much my friend!